# javascript offsetTop property both successful and has an error at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, offset

The codes below are executing successfully:

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function windowScroll() {
    var elems = ['section-1', 'section-2', 'section-3', 'section-4'];
    elems.forEach(function(elem) {
        if(window.pageYOffset >= $(`#${elem}`).offsetTop - $('.banner-header').offsetHeight) {
            var li = document.querySelectorAll('.banner-header > nav > a');
            for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                li[i].classList.remove('active-nav-item');
            }
            $(`.banner-header > nav > a[href='#${elem}']`).classList.add('active-nav-item');
        } else {
            $(`.banner-header > nav > a[href='#${elem}']`).classList.remove('active-nav-item');
        }
    });
}

function elementEvent(element, onEvent, eventCallback) {
    if(element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(onEvent, eventCallback, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent(onEvent, eventCallback);
    }
}

elementEvent(window, 'scroll', windowScroll);
```

I just noticed something when I opened the console that displayed this error message referring to line 6:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null

What's with `offsetTop` property that makes it complicated? What should I change in my code to make this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with `offsetTop`. However, your error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null` means that the *parent* object is `null`, and `null.offsetTop` doesn't exist. So it looks like `` $(`#${elem}`) `` is returning `null` for some element. Make sure each of the elements in your array exists in the DOM.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with ```$(`#${elem}`)```, you're just trying to get an element with the id `elem`. But if that element doesn't exist then you'll get the error because then the function returns `null` and `null.offsetTop` will cause the TypeError.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks, buddy